# Почему не работает jQuery $.post()

Tags: jquery, post

пример нерабочего кода:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
   <script>
     function p(){
         $.post('/test2.php', {p: 1});
     }
   </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href='#' onclick='p()'>P</a>
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['p'])) {echo "123";}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

пример рабочего кода:

```
echo "<a class='delete' onclick='$.post(\"../table.php\",{delete: 1}, function(){location.href=\"../table.php\"});'>Delete</a>";

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $del_query = mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM table WHERE login = '$login'");
    echo "<script>location.href='../table.php'</script>";
```

Comment: что значит не работает?

Comment: не работает код... при клике ничего не происходит

Comment: просто добавьте return false; в конце функции. и да, что, по-Вашему, должно происходить?

Comment: ничего не изменило...

Comment: почему вы решили, что ничего не происходит? не происходит запрос? не получаете ответ? что?

Comment: логично код `if(isset($_POST['p']))` должен выводить `echo` если post исполнился

Comment: ну вообще - не совсем так :-) куда по вашему он должен это вывести?

Comment: вы выполняете ajax запрос, соответственно, текущая страница никак не меняется. Вы можете посмотреть во вкладке Network(сеть) в инструментах разработчика в браузере, что запрос выполняется, и даже что-то возвращает, но вы просто не используете ответ поэтому думаете, что ничего не происходит

Comment: `test2.php` это текущая страница? или какая-то другая?

Comment: в тело документа... я упростил код для вопроса, но у меня в принципе `if(isset($_POST))` при одинаковых условиях то рабоет, то нет.. не понимаю почему

Comment: `test2.php` - текущая

Comment: при одинаковых условиях он не может по разному работать, значит что-то все-таки отличается. в данном случае - вы не используете ответ от сервера, соответственно текущая страница не меняется никак. Если реальный код другой - покажите пример

Comment: как правильно отправить запрос, чтобы `echo` вывело хоть что-то?

Comment: ну вот пример тоже "нерабочего" кода: `<img class='del_pare' onclick='$.post(\"../header.php\",{del_pare: 1}, function(){location.href=\"../header.php\"})' src='../all/c.png' />` если поставить `if(isset($_POST['del_pare'])) { //код }` то ничего не произойдет...

Comment: посмотрите документацию к [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) - после параметров, можно передать функцию которая примет ответ

Comment: если посмотрите внимательно - здесь у функции `post` три параметра, а в вашем посте - 2. Причем тут в обработчике производится редирект и теряются все данные :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы работало в такой разметке, как сейчас, не используйте jquery - достаточно просто формы:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="p" />
            <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['p'])) {echo "123";}
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Если непременно нужно jQuery меняйте разметку, например так:

во-первых, переносим php-код в начало файла

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['p'])) { //если пост параметр задан
        echo "123"; // выводим в выходной поток строку
        die(); // завершаем обработку страницу, после этой команды код не будет выполняться, и в выходной поток не будет добавлен html.
    }
?>
```

Далее

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script>
            function p(){
                $.post(location.href, {p: 1}, 
                    function(data){// success callback - выполняется при удачном запросе, если сервер вернул ответ HTTP 200 OK, первый параметр - то что мы записали в выходной поток, в нашем случае: 123
                        // далее с помощью jQuery выбираем элемент с id="response", и с помощью функции append - добавляем значение нашего параметра data в этот элемент
                        $('#response').append(data);
                    }
                );
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href='#' onclick='p()'>P</a>
        <div id="response"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

подробнее о функция jQuery в справке:

[$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [$.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: согласен, форма здесь работает как надо, но в определенном коде мне нужно именно `$.post()` запрос, который у меня почему-то в одном случае работает, в другом нет...

Comment: @Бодя, нужно конкретно рассматривать случаи, как уже говорил - в обработчике успешного ответа, например, у вас происходит редирект

Comment: спасибо, код подошел буду разбираться! =)

Comment: только вот так и не понял почему в случае `<a class='delete' onclick='$.post(\"../table.php\",{delete: 1}, function(){location.href=\"../table.php\"});'>Delete</a> <? if(isset($_POST['delete'])){}>?` все работает, а тут нет...

Comment: добавь этот код полностью в оригинальный пост, так не очень понятно что именно там есть. И с чего ты взял, что этот код работает?

Comment: добавил, можете посмотреть..?

Comment: забавный код :-) в нем все завязано на то, что в `table.php` данные подгружаются из базы, поэтому когда по пост запросу удаляется что-то из базы и потом делается редирект на себя же, данные подгружаются уже, естественно, без удаленной строчки

Comment: в общем плохой код :-) не надо так писать. В этом случае как раз больше подошел бы подход с формой.

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться ... но как правильно выполнить такой запрос? послать `$.post()` на другой php файл?

Comment: @Бодя, такой. это какой? :-) все зависит от того что вы хотите получить

Comment: я хочу: при клике на ссылку выполнить (желательно асинхронно) php код :)

Comment: в ответе - второй пример как раз это и делает: шлет запрос. получает ответ, что-то делает с ответом. по большому счету не важно слать на ту же страницу или нет.

Comment: скажите я правильно понял что: средством`.append()` весь контент подгружается в `<div>`, а в нем уже исполняется php ?

Comment: нет, не правильно. [$.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: тогда что такое data? заранее извиняюсь за такие вопросы... я начинающий =)

Comment: минутку, сейчас подредактирую ответ

Comment: @Бодя, обновил ответ, добавил комментарии и ссылки на документацию к функциям jQuery

Comment: понял, еще раз спасибо за содержательные ответы и уделенное время! ^_^

Comment: @Бодя, Пожалуйста :-)

Answer (score 0):

**test.php**

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
   <script>
     function p(){
         $.post('/test2.php', {p: 1}, function(data){
             alert(data);
         });
     }
   </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href='#' onclick='p(); return false'>P</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['p'])) {echo $_POST['p'];}
?>
```

Comment: запрос на ту же страницу

Comment: это вопрос, предложение, требование? Я показал как обычно это используется

Comment: это условие почерпнутое из комментариев к основному посту :-)

Comment: В `alert()` отобрается весь исходный код, но `echo` ничего не выводит :(

Comment: автор вопроса может думать что оно так лучше всего работает, но это не может быть не требование. еще раз - я best practice показываю

Comment: @Бодя прошу обратить внимание, что файла два в моем примере

Comment: уже лучше, потому что `alert()` выводит 1, однако в test2.php так и ничего не изменилось. к тому же я заинтересован в ссылке именно на текущую страницу